# JavaServer Faces (JSF) and Twitter BootStrap: h:outputStylesheet and relative urls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2

I'm using JavaServer Faces (JSF) to define layouts for pages which use Twitter BootStrap for styling (this question however is not strictly specific to BootStrap).

I defined the import of the bootstrap css stylesheet file and it works correctly except that it doesn't correctly interpret image urls inside the bootstrap css stylesheet.

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
```

Therefore a line like the one below inside bootstrap.css is not correctly finding the correct img file.

```
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

Am I missing something? how do I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: See lostinicelands answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013057/how-do-i-add-background-images-in-a-jsf-application-using-richfaces-and-css (not the accepted answer but it is the highest voted answer)

Comment: wow, changing all url instances inside css file with an EL seems convoluted. Didn't JSF come with a better solution? this seems a big hack to me.