# how to set background image in jsf

Tags: css, jsf, resources, background-image

how to set background image in jsf.i want to set (imag.jpg)as background. the images

are placed at resouces/images/imag.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"        
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">  

    <h:head>  
        <title>JSF Example</title>                  
        <style>               
        .Bimage{background-image:url("resources/images/imag.jpg"); }        
        </style>   

    </h:head>  
    <h:body styleClass="Bimage">  

    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="download.jpg"> </h:graphicImage>    

     <h3>JSF 2 Example</h3>  
     <h:form>

        <h:inputText value="#{hello.name}"></h:inputText>  

     </h:form>  

    </h:body>  
</html>
```

Comment: appropriate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033828/2459449

Comment: thanks for tour reply..i changed like this <style>               
          
          .Bimage{background-image:url("#{resources['images:image1.jpg']}"); }      
        </style>   but not getting

Comment: `resource` without `s`. And depending on what you have inside <style> tag, the definition CSS code should looke like: `.Bimage{background-image:url("#{resource['images:image1.jpg']}");}`. Better to copy-paste it.

Comment: <style>               
   
             .Bimage{background-image:url("#{resource['images:image1.jpg']}");}
        </style>   
                chaged like that also but not getting

Comment: The image name is "image1" or "imag" ?

Answer (score 4):

Change the css .Bimage by the following code

```
.Bimage{
     background-image:url(#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/imag.jpg);
 }
```

or

```
.Bimage{
     background-image:url(/Project_Name/resources/images/imag.jpg);
 }
```